# Memoization in Python persisting between requests

Tags: python, django, request, memoization

I came across this technique earlier today but am not sure how it really works.  I don't think it really matters for this example but I'm using Django for the app.

```
def post_to_endpoint(request, key=None):
    if not hasattar(post_to_endpoint, '__my_memo__'):
        post_to_endpoint.__my_memo__ = {
            "key1": "url" + "path",
            "key2": "url2" + "path",
            "key3": "url3" + "path",
            "key4": "url4" + "path",
        }

    if key:
        url = post_to_endpoint.__my_memo__.get(key, None)

        if url:
            # make my request here

    # return the response
```

I understand in this contrived example it's probably a micro-optimization.  In my functions I would just recreate that `dict` on every call.  On a basic level I understand that this `dict` is stashed in something called `func_dict`, but what I don't really understand is how it lives in between requests.

My understanding from a PHP background is that the whole framework is initialized on every request, but perhaps that is not the case with Python/Django/WSGI? I'm also pretty weak on understanding how all of this is run with processes/threads, maybe this information is kept-alive there?  I would have expected something like this would need to be done in some sort of persisted cache, but obviously this is not the case.

Also, a poster elsewhere mentioned memoization could also be achieved by `import`ing a dictionary, but I also don't understand how that would live between requests.

Comment: You've answered the question yourself. A WSGI app runs in a separate process (or many processes), which persists for many requests.

Comment: You have some options here, use a ddbb as redis to share information or even an mmap (not really sure about this one but I think it could work)

Comment: Use a caching system like memcached or Redis

Comment: @DanielRoseman So in this case my `function` object only gets "initialized" the one time when WSGI starts and after that it stays alive as long as the WSGI process is alive?  I guess I would have expected it to "die" or get garbage collected or something when it was no longer needed.

Comment: One time per process, yes - usually you'd have several processes running at the same time. And the server will occasionally kill and restart a process, for various reasons. So this type of caching is really only good for small speedups; you can't rely on things being in the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Daniel Roseman answered this in the comments:

"You've answered the question yourself. A WSGI app runs in a separate process (or many processes), which persists for many requests"

Comment: you could also look to https://github.com/anexia-it/django-request-cache